# Redirection by querying database value like stackoverflow.com URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

So I use the following htaccess code to redirect the URLs to clean looking URLs but, now what I need to happen is to have the original URLs to redirect to the new clean URLS.

**Example**

Original URL:

```
example.com/search/store_info.php?store=113&dentist=Dr.%20John%20Doe
```

Clean URL:

```
example.com/search/113/dr-john-doe
```

What I need is the "*ORIGINAL URL*" to redirect to the "*CLEAN URL*". Reason why I need this to happen is that both URLs are showing up in Google searches.

I only want the clean URL to show up and anytime the original URL is used it should automatically redirect to the clean URL. It currently doesn't do that.

**Here is my htaccess file.**

```
ErrorDocument 404 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /search/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /store_info\.php\?store=([a-z0-9]+)&dentist=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([^\s.]*)[.\s]+(.*)$ $1/$2-$3 [NC,DPI,E=DONE:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DONE} =1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/([^\s.]+)$ $1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ store_info.php?store=$1&dentist=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

I've read about RedirectMatch however I don't know where to implement it into my htaccess file.

Comment: @anubhava it doesn't redirect.. so if I go to `example.com/search/store_info.php?store=113` without the  "&dentist=Dr.%20John%20Doe" in the URL it goes to the original URL and does not convert to the clean URL version.  I'm looking to change that to where the `example.com/search/store_info.php?store=113` also goes to the clean URL. 

I've tried 
`Redirect 301 /search/store_info.php?store=118 http://www.example.com/search/118/John-Doe-Dental-Group/`

Comment: might I add that the `&dentist=Dr.%20John‌​%20Doe` gets added the to URL string by a button from the previous page.  so the `example.com/search/‌​store_info.php?store=‌​113` is the original URL that grabs the dentist name from the URL to then uses the htaccess file to create the clean URL.

Comment: @anubhava so there isn't a way to do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453161/rewriting-old-urls-to-pretty-urls-and-redirect-old-urls-to-new-with-htaccess)?   I know there is a way in web.config files. but I can't figure out in htaccess.

Comment: can't the htaccess file function something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x6vtcmbg/)? I'm just looking to take the original URL insert it into the htaccess file and then redirect it as a 301 to the NEW/clean URL

Comment: How can the "static value" be added to my existing htaccess file? and will the "static value" have to be created for each URL as it does for the web config file?

Comment: @anubhava isn't there a way to take the store id # and convert that to the clean url by pulling the "dentists name" from the database that is in correlation to that particular id #? So in other words if someone goes to `store_info.php?store=‌​118` then the htaccess file would know to convert that to the following `example.c‌​om/search/118/John-Do‌​e-Dental-Group/` because it knows that the dentist that is associated with the store id # 118 is the "John Doe Dental Group". Can this even be done with a htaccess file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121172/discussion-between-antivinegar-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `store_info.php` have code like this:

```
<?php
$store = $_GET['store'];

if (empty($store)) {
   header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
   exit;
}

$dentist = $_GET['dentist']);

// pull dentist from DB by store id. Create this function in PHP and
// query your database
$dentistFromDB = preg_replace('/[\h.]+/', '-', $row['businessName']);

// DB returns an empty or no value
if (empty($dentistFromDB)) {
   header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
   exit;
}

// DB returned value doesn't match the value in URL
if ($dentistFromDB != $dentist) {
   // redirect with 301 to correct /<store>/<dentist> page
   header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header('Location: /' . $store . '/' . $dentistFromDB);
   exit;
}

// rest of the PHP code should come now

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to clutter your htaccess file anymore with arbitrary rules/directives. The current set of rules, with the `%{THE_REQUEST}` matching, and later with the `%{ENV=DONE}` conditionals are more than enough.

Just wait a few days for google to crawl your pages again, and the older unclean urls will disappear. You could also search around in Google Webmaster Tools to see if this can be triggered manually.

PS: You can remove the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .` line from your first rule.